# 48bit RGB single pixel value

Tags: vb.net, rgb

3 RGB values are represented with a single one value in some image processing applications.

For example: The single value for RGB(2758, 5541, 4055) is 4542.64

There are some questions related on how to obtain single pixel values from 8bit RGB images but none works with 48bit RGB images. How can I obtain that value?

If I do (2758 + 5541 + 4055) / 3 the result is 4118 which is near but not the same.

Comment: Are you using `System.Drawing` or  the `System.Windows.Media.Imaging` namespace classes to open the image?

Comment: Opening the image is not a problem, I want to represent 3 values (RGB) from x pixel with 1 unique value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to determine the grayscale formula used to arrive at that given value.  I suggest that you read [Seven grayscale conversion algorithms](http://www.tannerhelland.com/3643/grayscale-image-algorithm-vb6/) by Tanner Helland.

Based on your example of:

> The single value for RGB(2758, 5541, 4055) is 4542.64

It appears that value is computed using the formula:

> Gray = (Red * 0.3 + Green * 0.59 + Blue * 0.11)